# How to use a custom image in MapBox instead of any map?

Tags: ios, mapbox

I'm looking for making a iPhone map application for indoor navigation in our office using mapbox. 
I'm not talking about custom icon image on marker or cacheing map for offline use.
Is this possible to create a simple iPhone app with MapBox which uses my own building map as image source?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You want to use [TileMill](http://tilemill.com) to create a map from the image, either hosting it online or exporting it to an MBTiles file (essentially a SQLite file full of tiles) that you can read directly in the app using `RMMBTilesSource`.

Here is a guide on making the map: http://mapbox.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/